# Convert tsql query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

Sorry for code not being in English.

I have this T-SQL code:

```sql
select terminRez
from TerminRezervacije t
where not exists (select TerminRezervacijeID
                  from Rezervacija as r 
                  where t.TerminRezervacijeID = r.TerminRezervacijeID 
                    and r.DatumRezervacije = '2021-01-14')
```

That works in SQL, but I don't know how to replicate with LINQ.

This SQL code returns all appointment times that are not booked on x date

I have a linq expression for `selectListItem` that returns all appointment times

```cs
model.TerminRezervacije = db.TerminRezervacije
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = p.TerminRezervacijeID.ToString(),
        Text = p.terminRez
    }).ToList();
```

If needed I will provide same code in English.

I am stuck here and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: If you have navigation properties then `db.TerminRezervacije.Where(x => !x.Rezervacijas.Any(y => y.Rezervacija == date))` should work, though if you're using EF Core this might not work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before it can be done by `Any` operator which equal to SQL `EXISTS` .

```cs
var date = ned DateTime(2021, 1, 14);
var query = 
   from t in ctx.TerminRezervacije
   where !ctx.Rezervacija.Where(r => t.TerminRezervacijeID == r.TerminRezervacijeID 
             && r.DatumRezervacije == date).Any()
   select t.terminRez;
```